# GTM Blocking Trigger Not Working

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a blocking trigger set up on a GTM tag that should prevent the tag from firing in a non-production environment.  The trigger is set up to fire only when the page hostname contains a string unique to the dev/staging environment URLs.

As you can see in step 2 of the GTM summary, I set up a test tag (green box) to confirm that the trigger is firing prior to the tag containing the trigger exception (red boxes).
[image]

Step 3 is a custom event firing from the dataLayer.  The green box tag is the tag that I want to fire in a non-production environment and the red box tag is the tag containing the blocking trigger which I would expect to prevent the tag from firing.
[image]

Here is a look inside of the red box tag that should not fire.  You can see that the blocking trigger recognizes the dev/stage URL but for some reason the `_event` is showing a red X.
[image]

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that the blocking trigger wasn't working because the tag had two different trigger types. The blocking trigger was a page view type and once while the normal trigger was a custom event.  To fix the issue, I changed my blocking trigger to fire on the same custom event as the firing trigger.

Comment: If you want to make this blocking trigger general for various other tags to be blocked on this environment, you can set it to be an Event trigger, matching .* as RegExp. (Matching any event name.) This way you can reuse this same blocking trigger to prevent running tags, bound to other type of triggers.

Comment: For people finding this question from Google, any blocking trigger will be ignored for a tag fired as a "setup" tag in a sequence for another tag (whose triggers and blockers are themselves satisfied); thus, a usually blocked tag will be fired. To work around this, it's best to apply the same (or similar) blocking trigger to the tag triggering, in turn, the setup tag.